# Return the currently selected object

Tags: vb.net, select

The code says everything, if I press F1 and I'm already with Button1 selected, then it should select Button2 and vice-versa.

```
If keyData = Keys.F1 Then
     If Button1.Select() = True Then
          Button2.Select()
     ElseIf Button2.Select() = True Then
          Button1.Select()
     Else
          Button1.Select()
     End If
End If
```

But the expression "Button2.Select() = True" doesn't return a value.

Comment: `[Control].Select()` is a method (void/sub), not a property. You probably want `[Button].Focused`.

Comment: `Button.Select` is a function to activate the control. What you want is `Button1.Focused` to check if the control is currently have the focus.

Comment: You could write it as: `dim buttons = {Button1, Button2} If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then buttons.First(Function(b) Not b.Focused)?.Select() end If`

Comment: Nice! And if I've more than 2 buttons?

Comment: The build a `List(Of Button)` from the `Form.Controls` collection. You can use the Tag or another property of choice to determine which are the ones you care about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.F1 Then
        If ActiveControl.Name = "Button1" Then
            Button2.Select()
        Else
            Button1.Select()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Actually, F1 is a poor choice because it is traditionally the "Help" key.

Answer (score 0):

We can use form keydown (set form keypreview property to true) or use button previewkeydown like these:

```
Private Sub Button1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Button1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
        Button2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Button2.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
        Button1.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```